# Unexpected text concatenation when performing database inserts

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

```
import bs4
import sqlite3
from urllib.request import urlopen as ureq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup


#crawling pages in website
for page in range(2, 32):
    my_url = 'https://www.bproperty.com/en/dhaka/apartments-for-sale/page-{}/'.format(page)

    zclient = ureq(my_url)

    data_html = zclient.read()

    zclient.close()

    data_soup = soup(data_html, "html.parser")

    contents = data_soup.findAll("li", {"class": "ef447dde"})

  #extracting needed data only
    for container in contents:
        Ad_Title = container.a["title"]
        amount = container.findAll("div", {"class": "cd6d5974 d8b3c34d"})
        price = amount[0].text
        area = container.findAll("div", {"class": "_7afabd84"})
        property_location = area[0].text
        category = container.findAll("div", {"class": "_9a4e3964"})
        listing_category = category[0].text
        size = container.findAll("div", {"class": "_22b2f6ed"})
        sq_ft = size[0].text
        rooms = container.findAll("span", {"class": "b6a29bc0"})
        bed_rooms = rooms[0].text
        bath_rooms = rooms[1].text
        image = container.img["src"]
        important_stuff = str(container.script)

     #connecting to the database
        database = "properties1.db"
        conn = sqlite3.connect(database)

     #creating a table in sqlite3
        conn.execute("""
         CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS adverts (
         "Ad_Title"    TEXT DEFAULT 'Buy Now!',
         "price"    TEXT,
         "property_location"    TEXT,
         "listing_category"    TEXT,
         "sq_ft"    TEXT,
         "bed_rooms"    TEXT DEFAULT 2,
         "bath_rooms"    TEXT DEFAULT 1,
         "image"    TEXT
         );""")

        cursor = conn.cursor()


        sqlite_insert_query = """INSERT INTO adverts
                         (Ad_Title, price, property_location, listing_category, sq_ft, bed_rooms, bath_rooms, image) 
                          VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ,?);"""

        data_tuple = (Ad_Title, price, property_location,
                  listing_category, sq_ft, bed_rooms, bath_rooms, image)
#seeding the database
        cursor.execute(sqlite_insert_query, data_tuple)
        conn.commit()

conn.close()
```

[For example: if the apartment size is 1300sqft and it has 3 rooms and 3 bathrooms, the sq_ft entry in databse shows 331300 sqft. But my code looks ok or i'm just blind.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cw7R6.png)

Comment: From your example erroneous value 331300 It looks like 3(rooms) and 3(bathrooms) are appended to size i.e 1300.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class("class": "_22b2f6ed") has all the 3 data in it i.e rooms, bathrooms and area that is why you are seeing all those 3 values appended(331300).

So you have to jump to 3rd index on span class({"class": "b6a29bc0"}) which is area and you should see the right answer area there.

```
# size = container.findAll("div", {"class": "_22b2f6ed"})
size = container.findAll("span", {"class": "b6a29bc0"})
sq_ft = size[2].text
```